# How to load data from a old virtual disk generated using PGP 6.0.2?

Tags: windows, windows-10, pgp, openpgp, virtual-disk

I have a virtual disk file (.pgd) and I think that I remember the passphrase, is there possible recovery my data? I have try install the PGP Freeware 6.0.2 but it not run in windows 10. I did some search in symantec but I not found the direct substitute of PGP Freeware. Could someone point which software I can use to try recovery my data? On the other hand, if my passphrase is not correct, would exist other way of recovery my data?

Comment: Can you run Windows XP in a virtual machine?

Comment: I'm trying to do this test, but I still can not install XP correctly using Hyper-V, I could not configure the network connectivity. :((